# How to add delivery addresses to order history page on Bigcommerce?

Tags: html, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'd like to be able to add the address that the order has been delivered to next to the order number, so it is visible without clicking into the orders. As seen in the attached picture in red text.

I have tried copying the address lines out of order-contents.html into the orders-list.html section and this is likely why i'm getting an "undefined" return when I try but I'm unable to figure out how to fix this. As seen in the attached, what I am referring to is in green text.

[image: example]